# onDestroy or dispose in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose, ondestroy, application-lifecycle

I am developing a note app, and I want to save my note when I closed the app (when removing the app from recent apps).
I tried `dispose()` method but it did not work.
I tried :

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print(state);
    final isDetached = state == AppLifecycleState.detached;}
```

but it did not work too. it does not print detached status, just it prints `AppLifecycleState.paused` `AppLifecycleState.inactive` `AppLifecycleState.resume`

so what should I do here!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this if you're observing the app lifecycle state:

```dart
class AppLifecycleReactor extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppLifecycleReactor({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppLifecycleReactor> createState() => _AppLifecycleReactorState();
}

class _AppLifecycleReactorState extends State<AppLifecycleReactor> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print(state);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Widgets;
  }
}
```

to summarise:

- `with WidgetsBindingObserver` after `extends State`
- `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);` in `initstate`
- `WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);` in `dispose`

For more info check: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

Comment: Yes my code looks like this, but print method prints  paused, inactive, resume, but when i close the app it will not print detach

Comment: @wafaasisalem There is an issue on the GH regarding detached not being called https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57594

Answer (score 0):

dispose() function is only visible in **StatefulWidget**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final AppRouter _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: _appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // dispose your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: I know, but when i put the code in it, it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: Ah, I see your concern, if your update DB action take time, you also can do it in a service and call it in dispose or onDestroy after app release.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [Firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) and save for example after every edit, or after 500ms after an edit using `rx.debounce` from [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart).

You cannot rely on the app really being able to execute dispose or even save something to a database when it is closed. Removing an app from the recent list ends the app very quickly (kills the app), that's why it works even for hung/crashed apps.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use shared preferences in that case. Share preferences are used to save data in your local storage and the implementation is also very simple. and don't worry it won't make your app laggy or slow. It works very smoothly

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

do upvote if helpful

Comment: Thank you, I know how to use shared preferences, but the thing is where should I use it? suppose you were writing your note and your phone closed or you closed the recent apps by mistake where should I put my code?